# Mouse wheel scrolling not working on some area of website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In some area of a website, mouse scrolling not working.

It will be easy to understand if you visit the link.

[Link1](http://23.229.224.7/~menloweb/our-properties/)

In Link1, scrolling not working inside the listing.

[Link2](http://23.229.224.7/~menloweb/why-menlo/)

In Link2, the scrolling not working over the youtube embedded video.

Any solution to allow scrolling over these areas?

Comment: which js library have you use for scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the YouTube video and the Buildout Real Estate Listing are iframe embeds. The theme you have installed uses Nice Scroll (https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com), and as stated in the plugin issues section at github, it doesn't play nicely with iframes (since the mouse wheel movement is not being detected):

https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues/651

You might want to get rid of the Nice Scroll plugin by removing the "nice-scroll-on" class from the body tag at your templates or by deactivating it at line 1445 in scripts.js, otherwise this won't work until the mousewheel behavior is fixed.

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Scroll | niceScroll
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

//Comment the following block

/*
if( $('body').hasClass('nice-scroll-on') && window.innerWidth >= 768 && ! navigator.userAgent.match(/(Android|iPod|iPhone|iPad|IEMobile|Opera Mini)/))
    {
        $('html').niceScroll({
            autohidemode        : false,
            cursorborder        : 0,
            cursorborderradius  : 5,
            cursorcolor         : '#222222',
            cursorwidth         : 10,
            horizrailenabled    : false,
            mousescrollstep     : ( window.mfn.nicescroll ) ? window.mfn.nicescroll : 40,
            scrollspeed         : 60
        });

        $('body').removeClass('nice-scroll-on').addClass('nice-scroll');
        niceScrollFix();
    }
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

you included some nice-scroll plugin in  your code so it has its own scrolling, when you add this plugin it adds overflow-y:hidden to your html element, try remove that then scroll works in entire page. i have tried it using firebug then it works perfect

Comment: This will add scroll on page

Comment: any way he already  has  scroll with that plugin. Even he is not asking about scroll

Comment: and he has to remove that nice plugin js